# Bash | Copy files to multiple folders and delete them script

Tags: bash, find, copy, cp

I have to copy some files (100 kbs/file) from one folder X to folder Y and B after that I have to delete the files not the folders. Easy until now but folder X will almost continously receive files and I might think that there can be a case when the script will first copy 5 files to X then 8 to Y and delete 10 because there are files coming continously.

I have tested with 2000 files and everything worked great. But I have to be 100% sure that I don't lose any file.

This is my script:

```
cp -R -v /$RootPath/MAPADMIN/$Client/Inbox/* /$RootPath/$Client/Inbox/ >> log.txt
cp -R -v /$RootPath/MAPADMIN/$Client/Inbox/* /$RootPath/Backup/$Client/Inbox >> log.txt
find /$RootPath/MAPADMIN/$Client/Inbox/ -maxdepth 2 -type f -delete >> log.txt
```

This script is PERFECT for my situation but I have to be 100% sure that I have 0% lost files.
Is there someone that have tested something like this so a longer time or someone who can help me improve it.

Thank you!

Comment: Note that your source files could also change (grow) during the copy... I would loop over the source files and, in each iteration, compute the md5sum of the current file, copy it to its two destination folders and check that its md5sum did not change. If it didn't, delete the source file. If it did, delete the two copies but not the source. Would it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated like this:

```
files=(*.*)

if [ "$files" != "*.*" ]
then

for file in "${files[@]}"; do

        cp "/$RootPath/$1/Outbox/$folder$file" /$RootPath/MAPADMIN/$1/Outbox/$folder
        mv "/$RootPath/$1/Outbox/$folder$file" /$RootPath/Backup/$1/Outbox/$folder
done
fi
```

I am searching for every folder into that dir, and then in every folder I am searching for every file and I am going one by one. 
3 months left and almost 50,000 files were moved using the script above with 0% loss.

I hope it will be helpful for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use in this case rsync it's more reliable.

```
rsync  -arv /$RootPath/MAPADMIN/$Client/Inbox/ $RootPath/$Client/Inbox 2>&1 >> log.txt
rsync  -arv /$RootPath/MAPADMIN/$Client/Inbox/ /$RootPath/Backup/$Client/Inbox 2>&1 >> log.txt
find /$RootPath/MAPADMIN/$Client/Inbox/ -maxdepth 2 -type f -delete >> log.txt
```

Comment: Can you please provide me an example based on my script ?